# Azure powershell function-Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: azure, function, powershell, .net-core-2.2

I'm working on ***Azure powershell functions*** in Visual Studio code to connect to ExcahngeOnlineManagement. Trying to connect to EXO using "***Connect-ExchangeOnline***" cmdlt with a certificate inside function i.e.
**Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword $secure -AppId $AppId -Organization $org**

**getting below error:**

Result: Errors reported while executing profile.ps1. See logs for detailed errors. Profile location: D:\PowershellFunction\profile.ps1.
Exception: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Stack:    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1
output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumerable input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings) [8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings) [8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke() [8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.PowerShell.PowerShellExtensions.InvokeAndClearCommands(PowerShell pwsh) in  C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\PowerShell\PowerShellExtensions.cs:line 19 [8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.PowerShell.PowerShellManager.InvokeProfile(String profilePath) in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\PowerShell\PowerShellManager.cs:line 178 [8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.PowerShell.PowerShellManager.Initialize() in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\PowerShell\PowerShellManager.cs:line 113 [8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.PowerShell.PowerShellManagerPool.CheckoutIdleWorker(String requestId, String invocationId, String functionName, ReadOnlyDictionary`2 outputBindings) in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\PowerShell\PowerShellManagerPool.cs:line 100
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.RequestProcessor.ProcessInvocationRequest(StreamingMessage request) in C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\RequestProcessor.cs:line 262.
[8/6/2020 5:22:35 PM] Executed 'Functions.PSTest' (Failed, Id=a691463c-267c-446c-98cd-b1a496a935d9)

**Azure powershell functions are dependent on .Netcore 2.2.** Even upgraded powershell to 7.0.3 version.My windows framework is 4.8.
Can anyone please help me to make it work using Azure powershell functions.